# Distance between two point processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, queueing-theory

> Is there a distance metric that we can use to see how close are two point processes?

If instead of point process, we deal with random variables, there are a bunch of distance metrics that we can use to see how close are they based on their probability density function such as relative entropy ( Kullback-Leibler divergence) and total variation distance. But, for point processes, this doesn't sound simple.

Since the number of arrivals for a point process is a random variable, one way I thought about is using distance metrics on the number of arrivals of the point processes. But, I think since number of arrivals is not a complete representation of a point process, we are missing some information about the closeness of those point processes, if we just use their number of arrival. Can you please let me know your ideas how I should proceed?

Also, please let me know any nice references to read.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Calculation-of-the-Kullback-Leibler-distance-Gruner-Johnson/64de2959541ef08c547c198b92a428094e879a45/pdf

Comment: Have a look at section 3.3 of: http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/framechno.pdf. This is the common way of defining a metric on the space of right-continuous functions (which the sample paths of point processes belong to).

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks. I already had read the paper but it was not enough. Is there anything else I could read?